# Компиляция JavaScript в машинный код

Tags: javascript, компиляция

Есть ли возможность компилировать программу на JavaScript в машинный код(байт-код java не подходит)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Статически - нет. JavaScript слишком гибкий язык. Динамически - любой современный интерпретатор так и делает. Первым по этому пути пошел V8 (движок, который используется в Хроме и в node.js).

Comment: Добавьте инфу о `asm.js` и особенно `WebAssembly`.

Comment: @Other `asm.js` и `WebAssembly` - это про другое.

Comment: Дя? А что же тогда?

Comment: @Aid они используются для запуска в браузере программ, написанных на других языках, а не для компиляции js в бинарник.

Comment: Есть такое. Но уже ближе к компиляции.

Comment: @Aid ближе-то ближе, да только компиляция идет в *другую* сторону :-)

Comment: Я знаю, но это не отменяет того, что эти технологии достойны упоминания ИМХО. Однако, это Ваш ответ, я просто предложил.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такую штуку http://enclosejs.com... Позволяет компилировать JS в исполняемый файл. Единственное на выходе сильно большой файл получается. Hello, World! весит 22Мб.

Comment: Вангую - запихали интерпретатор (V8?) с скриптами в одну корзину.

Comment: Там в роде речь идёт о node.js, не о клиентском

Answer (score -1):

В FrameWork.Net входит Microsoft JScript Compiler - jsc.exe (Лежит в 
c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\FrameWork\ (ваша версия)\jsc.exe

Подробное описание jsc.exe /?

С его помощью компилируется в ".exe"

Нужно заметить что DOM - отсутствует по понятным причинам, но у вас есть полный набор средств работы с диском, реестром и прочими вещами...

Comment: Там очень старая версия языка

Comment: Если быть точным, то речь идет не о JavaScript, a о языке JScript.NET,  скриптовом языке программирования компании Майкрософт, являющийся реализацией стандарта ECMAScript. Ориентирован на работу в рамках платформы Microsoft .NET. Несмотря на сходный синтаксис, это принципиально другой язык. Он более строго типизирован, и компилируется, а не интерпретируется Со своими задачами  (а именно - автоматизация администрирования систем Microsoft Windows; создание страниц ASP) он не не плохо справляется.  (Последнее обновление 2010 год)

Comment: Тем более, раз это совсем другой язык.